# Creating a flowchart for an algorithm which receives values periodically

Tags: algorithm, flowchart

I'm new to programming. I want to create a flowchart for my algorithm. In my algorithm there is a coordinator which waits for values from several devices. Each time it receives a value, it does some operation on it and after finishing the operation, waits for the next value to come.

So my question is that should I put an oval at the end of the the flowchart to show  the end of each operation on a value or I should just connect the last rectangle (showing the last operation done on the received value) to the start part of the flowchart?

The attached photo is the flowchart I mean. Is it wrong to omit the end oval? If I put an end symbol (oval), won't it be wrong since the coordinator should wait for the next values?

[image: flowchart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a wait for values node before the start, which would go with a directed vertice into start and operation2 would go into the wait.

Your chart, as it is suggests that the next chunk of work is started right away when the current is finished, yet, you need to illustrate the fact that there might be a wait time. Take a look at this chart:

[image]

You see the "Wait for data processing result" node. This is the wait symbol, which you need before start, as your very first node.

Comment: Thanks, So I don't need an end symbol after operation2? All I need is a wait symbol before start and operation2 should be connected to this wait symbol, right?

Comment: @Pablo you can use an end symbol to note that the iteration was ended, but the big algorithm never ends. However, if you do not use an end symbol, that is, you associate the "end" to the big algorithm, then the start should be before the wait and the vertice from operation 2 should go into the wait.